# best way to run sql server management studio on linux

Tags: sql-server, ssms, linux, virtualisation

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.2 on my desktop and running sql server 2017 from docker.

I want to use sql server management studio to manage the server.

SO far now, I have a windows 7 enterprise with with ssms 17.9.1 and it works ok

It's really annoying having to boot a whole windows enterprise just for a single app, so I wanted to know if there's some better way to run it. A lighter or better integrated alternative.

that version of ssms doesn't seem to work with wine.

Answer (score 14):

You can't run Sql Server Management Studio on Linux. But there is an alternative that is provided by Microsoft called [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download?view=sql-server-2017). Not all features are available in Azure Data Studio that are available in Sql Server Management Studio - the main difference is that Azure Data Studio is missing a lot of the wizards that are available in SSMS.

> Use Azure Data Studio if you:
>
> - Need to run on macOS or Linux
> - Are connecting to a SQL Server 2019 big data cluster
> - Spend most of your time editing or executing queries
> - Need the ability to quickly chart and visualize result sets
> - Can execute most administrative tasks via the integrated terminal using sqlcmd or Powershell
> - Have minimal need for wizard experiences
> - Do not need to do deep administrative configuration
>
> Use SQL Server Management Studio if you:
>
> - Spend most of your time on database administration tasks
> - Are doing deep administrative configuration
> - Are doing security management, including user management, vulnerability assessment, and configuration of security features
> - Make use of the Reports for SQL Server Query Store
> - Need to make use of performance tuning advisors and dashboards
> - Are doing import/export of DACPACs
> - Need access to Registered Servers and want to control SQL Server services on Windows

The snippet above is taken from [Sql Server Blog](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2018/09/25/azure-data-studio-for-sql-server/) and provides a comparison of features.

If you are happy to pay for a tool, then take a look at [Aqua Data Studio](https://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio) and [SQL Maestro](https://www.sqlmaestro.com) which have quite a lot of features and a wide range of support for other database platforms.

Comment: Adding that ADS also includes many features not available in SSMS as called out in the referenced blog link.

Comment: Azure Studio is usable in Linux, but it is still too buggy.

Comment: Use Virtual Box and install it on there, set virtual box to bridged connection and you can do a large proportion of stuff there.

Comment: Azure Studio on linux can read .bak backup files and use them to restore a database from linux.

Comment: ADS doesnt read those files, @txyoji , the database engine does. Any application that can run T-SQL can `RESTORE` a backup.